# JavaScript not working in Firefox. Might be parseInt

Tags: javascript, firefox, parseint

The following script is working perfectly in most browser but not at all in Firefox.
If anyone has any thoughts it would be a great help. 
I have included jQuery
I am trying to make a sprite button.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {

var intval="";
var rewind ="";
$('#logo').hover(function(){
    if(intval==""){
        intval =window.setInterval(play_animation,30);
    }
},function(){
    window.clearInterval(intval);
    intval="";
    if(rewind==""){
        rewind=window.setInterval(rewind_animation,30);
    }
});

function play_animation(){
    //retrieve background x-coordinate because IE only recognize 'background-position
    var frame = $('#logo').css('background-position-x').split(' ');
    var framei =parseInt(frame[0].split('px'));
    if(framei > (-360)){
        var xpos =framei-40;
        $('#logo').css({'backgroundPosition':xpos+'px 0px'});
    }
}

function rewind_animation(){
    var frame = $('#logo').css('background-position-x').split(' ');
    var framei =parseInt(frame[0].split('px'));
    //if background position exist, rewind back to starting point
    if(framei ){
        var xpos =framei+40;
        $('#logo').css({'backgroundPosition':xpos+'px 0px'});
    }
    //when animation returns to starting point clear out the interval function
    if(framei==0){
        window.clearInterval(rewind);
        rewind="";
    }
}

});
</script>
```

AND the initial CSS:

```
#logo{
 background:url(circles2.jpg) 0px 0px no-repeat;
 height:40px;
 width:40px;
 display:block;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "not at all in Firefox"? Are you getting an error? Do you have one of the firefox developer add-ons (like webdeveloper) installed so you can see the specifics of the error?

Answer (score 3):

Where you have `var frame = $('#logo').css('background-position-x').split(' ');`

I think you actually want `var frame = $('#logo').css('background-position').split(' ');` (remove the "-x").  That fixes it for me.

Comment: Yep.  There is no `background-position-x` CSS property in the spec.  Some browsers just sort of made it up.